# How to calculate the difference of two sums in SQL

Tags: sql, grafana, clickhouse, having

I'm using Grafana to show some data from Clickhouse. The data comes from a table containing `itime`, `count` and some other columns.

```
id  method   count        itime
1    aaa      12     2021-07-20 00:07:06
2    bbb      9      2021-07-20 00:07:06
3    ccc      7      2021-07-20 00:07:07
...
```

Now I can execute the following SQL to get the sum of `count` between two `itime`s:

```
SELECT toUnixTimestamp(toStartOfMinute(itime)) * 1000 as t,
       method,
       sum(count) as c
FROM me.my_table
WHERE itime BETWEEN toDateTime(1631870605) AND toDateTime(1631874205)
      and method like 'a%'
GROUP BY method, t
HAVING c > 500
ORDER BY t
```

It works as expected.

Now, I want to select the `sum(count)` according to the difference between `sum(count) - sum(count)<--7-day-ago`. Something like `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... HAVING c - c<--7-day-ago >= 100`. But I don't know how.

Comment: Can you simplify this query of yours and remove the functions you have created(if we do not need them) ? Also, can you give us some more data(relevant data) and expected results from that data(because you say 7 days ago...and the examples are all on the same day...)

Comment: @VBoka Alright, in fact I'm working with Grafana & Clickhouse... Well, the data is just like that except that the `itime` changed. I'm sure that it stores lots of data, including the one 7 days ago.

Comment: @Akina I'm a newbie on DB. I thought they were all the same. In fact I'm working with Grafana & Clickhouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had some similar problem a while ago

please check the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/927c77/3)
to see the result press buttons: first- **build schema**, second: **run sql**

### naming

i assumed that you want for the same period A you selected a seven days later period B of time to compare (you need to be more specific, what you really looking for).

- period A = your selected time period (between *from* and *to*)
- period B = your selected time period one week in the past

### problem

this is a real delicate question, if i understood the question right.
your example is grouped by minute inside a period A. this means, you really need to have data in period A for every minute you have data in period B, otherwise you will ignore period B data inside your chosen period.

as you can see in the sqlfiddle, i made two query strings. the first one is working, but ignores B data. the second one does a right join (sadly mysql does not support full outer joins to show all in one table) and shows 2 ignored entries.

it even makes it worse, because you group by method too.
(in this case for the fiddle you have to change the last line of the join and add:)

```
as b on a.unix_itime = b.unix_itime and a.method = b.method
```

this means, you need for every selected method and period minutewise data.

it would be better if you group only by the method and not time, as you already use a time condition (period A) to keep it small.
or do the stepping bigger, by hour or day..

this code should fit your envirement (mysql does not support toUnixTimestamp, toStartOfMinute, toDateTime):

```sql
SELECT 
    a.unix_itime * 1000 as t,
    a.method,
    a.sum AS c,
    b.sum AS c2,
    ifnull(a.sum,0) - ifnull(b.sum,0) as diff,
    
FROM (select method, sum(count) as sum, toUnixTimestamp(toStartOfMinute(itime)) as unix_itime
      from my_table
      WHERE method like 'a%' and
          itime BETWEEN toDateTime(1631870605) 
                    AND toDateTime(1631874205)
      GROUP BY method, unix_itime) 
          as a

  LEFT JOIN (select method, sum(count) as sum, toUnixTimestamp(toStartOfMinute(itime + INTERVAL 7 DAY)) as unix_itime
            from my_table
            WHERE method like 'a%' and
                itime BETWEEN toDateTime(1631870605)- INTERVAL 7 DAY 
                          AND toDateTime(1631874205)- INTERVAL 7 DAY
            GROUP BY method, unix_itime) 
                as b on a.unix_itime = b.unix_itime and a.method = b.method

ORDER BY a.unix_itime;
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
create table test(D Date, Key Int64, Val Int64) Engine=Memory;

insert into test select today(), number, 100 from numbers(5);

insert into test select today()-7, number, 110 from numbers(5);
```

1. 

```sql
select sx.2 d1, Key, sumIf(sx.1, D=sx.2) s, sumIf(sx.1, D!=sx.2) s1 from (
select D, Key, arrayJoin([(s, D), (s, D + interval 7 day)]) sx
from (select D, Key, sum(Val) s from test group by D, Key)
)group by d1, Key
order by d1, Key;

┌─────────d1─┬─Key─┬───s─┬──s1─┐
│ 2021-09-10 │   0 │ 110 │   0 │
│ 2021-09-10 │   1 │ 110 │   0 │
│ 2021-09-10 │   2 │ 110 │   0 │
│ 2021-09-10 │   3 │ 110 │   0 │
│ 2021-09-10 │   4 │ 110 │   0 │
│ 2021-09-17 │   0 │ 100 │ 110 │
│ 2021-09-17 │   1 │ 100 │ 110 │
│ 2021-09-17 │   2 │ 100 │ 110 │
│ 2021-09-17 │   3 │ 100 │ 110 │
│ 2021-09-17 │   4 │ 100 │ 110 │
│ 2021-09-24 │   0 │   0 │ 100 │
│ 2021-09-24 │   1 │   0 │ 100 │
│ 2021-09-24 │   2 │   0 │ 100 │
│ 2021-09-24 │   3 │   0 │ 100 │
│ 2021-09-24 │   4 │   0 │ 100 │
└────────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

2. 

```sql
SELECT
    D,
    Key,
    Val,
    any(Val) OVER (PARTITION BY Key ORDER BY D ASC RANGE BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 7 PRECEDING) Val1
FROM test

┌──────────D─┬─Key─┬─Val─┬─Val1─┐
│ 2021-09-10 │   0 │ 110 │    0 │
│ 2021-09-17 │   0 │ 100 │  110 │
│ 2021-09-10 │   1 │ 110 │    0 │
│ 2021-09-17 │   1 │ 100 │  110 │
│ 2021-09-10 │   2 │ 110 │    0 │
│ 2021-09-17 │   2 │ 100 │  110 │
│ 2021-09-10 │   3 │ 110 │    0 │
│ 2021-09-17 │   3 │ 100 │  110 │
│ 2021-09-10 │   4 │ 110 │    0 │
│ 2021-09-17 │   4 │ 100 │  110 │
└────────────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is slightly ambiguous, but this could produce one possible meaning of the above.  If you still want to return overall `SUM(count)`, just add that to the select list.

```
SELECT toUnixTimestamp(toStartOfMinute(itime)) * 1000 AS t
     , method
     , SUM(count) AS c
     , SUM(count) - SUM(CASE WHEN itime < current_date - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN count END) AS c2
  FROM me.my_table
 WHERE method like 'a%'
 GROUP BY method, t
HAVING c2 >= 100
 ORDER BY t
;
```

Adjust as needed.

Maybe you didn't want to return the difference, just filter the groups returned.  If so, try this:

```
SELECT toUnixTimestamp(toStartOfMinute(itime)) * 1000 AS t
     , method
     , SUM(count) AS c
  FROM me.my_table
 WHERE method like 'a%'
 GROUP BY method, t
HAVING SUM(count) - SUM(CASE WHEN itime < current_date - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN count END) >= 100
 ORDER BY t
;
```